# Download set of files from FTP with Camel by rest call

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to download a set of files from ftp using camel route by rest call:
I'm trying the following:
   `from("cxfrs:bean:restndpoint")
                .pollEnrich("some ftp url")
                .to("destinationFilesLocation")
                .bean(MyBean.class);`
it works only for one file on ftp, and when I'm trying run it one more time it just waits for file. If I replace pollEnrich("some ftp url") wit from("some ftp url") Camels doesn't wait for rest call an just download files all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how the pollEnrich EIP pattern works. Its to poll a single message.

Your use case to download a set of FTP files via a REST call sounds more like you should use the Control Bus EIP pattern, where the REST call would trigger starting another route that performs FTP download.

See: http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sounds exactly what I need. Could you please point me to an example how route should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

```
    from("cxfrs:bean:restndpoint")
            .to("controlbus:route?action=start&routeId=ftpRouteId&async=true");

    from("some ftp url").routeId("ftpRouteId").noAutoStartup()
            .choice()
            .when(body().isNull())
                .to("direct:extract")
            .otherwise()
                .to("destinationFilesLocation");

    from("direct:extract")
            .to("controlbus:route?action=stop&routeId=ftpRouteId&async=true")
            .bean(MyBean.class);
```